# auth0 metadata push rules to user

Tags: node.js, typescript, metadata, auth0

I'm working on a project. Using `Auth0` for authentication. I can through the `Auth0` interface add a rule to a user like admin, customer etc.

What I want to do is **when a customer is authenticated and adds an account that I can then "push" back through to Auth0 that this person is a customer.** Has anyone done this?

I'm using `MEAN stack; Node, Express, Typescipt, Angular` etc. I think it will be added via node. I already have admin setup but because that will be minimal users.

I'm looking to do this with having to manually update the user each time.

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: I'm fiddling with it currently. Tried a few things along the lines of 

this.auth.userProfile.app_metadata.roles.push('administrator');

I'll keep at it but wondering if anyone has so far. I'm fine extracting from the metadata but wanted to see if I can use a push to say that someone is a customer, admin etc. but by code and not manually going into the interface.